# Print out map key values where key is a struct variable c++

Tags: c++, dictionary

```
struct cno{
    int sub;
};
```

A struct is taken as a key variable in map.

```
map<cno,int> s;
struct cno k;
```

I am trying to print the key value like this.

```
for(map<cno,int>::iterator it = s.begin();it!=s.end();it++){
    cout<<it->first<<endl;
}//Error
```

I have already overloaded < operator to compare the key values.

Comment: You need to overload `operator<<` for `cno`.

Answer (score 1):

All you need to do is (`it->first.sub`)

```
for(map<cno,int>::iterator it = s.begin();it!=s.end();it++){
    cout<<it->first.sub<<endl;
}
```

Why? `first` is of type `cno`, and you need to access desired element.

If you have implemented overload operator `<<` for this, please give the code here.

Answer (score 1):

This is how you `overload` an operator:

```
ostream& operator<<(ostream& out,cno &c){
    out<<c.sub<<endl;
    return out;
}
```

You need to overload **operators** in order to print,compare or process an element of an **user defined** object.Here we have to overload **ostream** object in order to print your **user defined** object.